Semantic release major version using conventional commits
So i have this semantic releases, set up and working with conventionl commits for minor and patch versions.
But i want it to work for major versions, so that when i add "!" exclamation mark, a major version upgrade occurs. But it doesnt seem to be working, im not sure what i need to add to the config
{
  "branches": [
    "master"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      {
        "preset": "conventionalcommits",
        "releaseRules": [
          {
            "type": "major",
            "release": "major"
          },
          {
            "type": "feat",
            "release": "minor"
          },
          {
            "type": "fix",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "perf",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "revert",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "docs",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "style",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "chore",
            "release": false
          },
          {
            "type": "refactor",
            "release": "patch"
          },
          {
            "type": "test",
            "release": false
          },
          {
            "type": "build",
            "release": false
          },
          {
            "type": "ci",
            "release": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      {
        "preset": "conventionalcommits",
        "presetConfig": {
          "types": [
            {
              "type": "major",
              "section": "Features"
            },
            {
              "type": "feat",
              "section": "Features"
            },
            {
              "type": "fix",
              "section": "Bug Fixes"
            },
            {
              "type": "perf",
              "section": "Performance Improvements"
            },
            {
              "type": "revert",
              "section": "Reverts"
            },
            {
              "type": "docs",
              "section": "Documentation",
              "hidden": true
            },
            {
              "type": "style",
              "section": "Styles",
              "hidden": true
            },
            {
              "type": "chore",
              "section": "Miscellaneous Chores",
              "hidden": true
            },
            {
              "type": "refactor",
              "section": "Code Refactoring"
            },
            {
              "type": "test",
              "section": "Tests",
              "hidden": true
            },
            {
              "type": "build",
              "section": "Build System",
              "hidden": true
            },
            {
              "type": "ci",
              "section": "Continuous Integration",
              "hidden": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": [
          "CHANGELOG.md"
        ],
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} CHANGELOG.md [ci skip]"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab",
      {
        "successComment": false
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/exec",
      {
        "prepareCmd": "echo ${nextRelease.version} > .next-version"
      }
    ]
  ]
}


Check this issue on the @semantic-release/commit-analyzer plugin : https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer/issues/413
It adds this rule {breaking: true, release: 'major'} to make it work.
